# postgres insert into is very slow

Tags: postgresql

I have a 'insert into table () select from' that is very slow.

**The select  takes only 3s.**

**But to insert 30k line, it takes more than 3 min.**

3 min for 30k lines, seems a lot for me (given that in 'real' I will have millions of lines).

I try many postgres optimizations but it's not really improving:
wal_buffers=8MB, fsync=off etc...

I simplified the request, to try to understand why it is so slow.

Here is what my request look like:

```
drop table if exists ODSBUS.DIM_INSCRIPTIONS_ETUDIANTS_TEST;
create table ODSBUS.DIM_INSCRIPTIONS_ETUDIANTS_TEST (
   ID_INSCRIPTION_ETU   VARCHAR(5),
   ID_NUM_INSCRIPTION_ETU VARCHAR(5) ,
   ID_HISTORIQUE        VARCHAR(5)                ,
   ID_INSCRIPTION_AP    VARCHAR(5)                ,
   ID_SEMESTRE          VARCHAR(5)                ,
   ID_PARITE_SEMESTRE   VARCHAR(5)                ,
   ID_ETUDIANT          VARCHAR(5)                ,
   ID_AP                VARCHAR(5)                ,
   ID_EC                VARCHAR(5)                ,
   ID_OBLIGATION_EC     VARCHAR(5)          ,
   ID_UE                VARCHAR(5)                ,
   ID_COMPOSANTE        VARCHAR(5)          ,
   ID_BOURSE            VARCHAR(5)                ,
   ID_ANNEE             VARCHAR(5)                ,
   FG_NEOBACHELIER      VARCHAR(5)          ,
   FG_AP_MAJEUR         VARCHAR(5)          ,
   DT_DEMISSION         VARCHAR(5)                ,
   FG_DEMISSIONNAIRE    VARCHAR(5)          
);


-- the insert
insert into odsbus.DIM_INSCRIPTIONS_ETUDIANTS_TEST (id_inscription_etu,
id_num_inscription_etu,
id_historique,
id_inscription_ap,
id_semestre,
id_parite_semestre,
id_etudiant,
id_ap,
id_ec,
id_obligation_ec,
id_ue,
id_composante,
id_bourse,
id_annee,
fg_neobachelier,
fg_ap_majeur,
dt_demission,
fg_demissionnaire) 
SELECT  '',
'' ,
'' ,
'' ,
'' ,
'' ,
'' ,
'' ,
'' ,
'',
'' ,
'' ,
'' ,
'' ,
'',
'',
'',
''
FROM ldzbus.scol_inscription_ap ap
 inner join dwhbus.dim_annees da on da.id_annee = ap.fann_key 
 inner join ldzbus.scol_inscription_etudiant sie on sie.fann_key = ap.fann_key and sie.idipl_numero = ap.idipl_numero 
 inner join odsbus.dim_etudiants et on et.id_numero = sie.etud_numero 
 inner join ldzbus.v_scol_maquette maq on maq.mrap_key = ap.mrap_key 
 inner join ldzbus.scol_inscription_ec iec on iec.idipl_numero = ap.idipl_numero and iec.mrec_key = maq.mrec_key and iec.imrec_semestre = ap.imrap_semestre 
 inner join ldzbus.scol_inscription_semestre sis on sis.idipl_numero = ap.idipl_numero and sis.mrsem_key = maq.mrsem_key 
 inner join ldzbus.scol_maquette_repartition_ec smre on smre.mrec_key = maq.mrec_key 
 inner join ldzbus.dept_domaine dd on dd.fdom_code = sie.fdom_code 
 inner join ldzbus.historique h on h.hist_numero = sie.hist_numero 
 inner join ldzbus.scol_maquette_repartition_ap smra on smra.mrap_key = ap.mrap_key 
 WHERE 1=1
limit 30000; 
--> more than 3 min
```

Note that the request use many different schema.

What can I try to make this insert take less time ?
Focus on the request? focus on tuning postgres ? tuning my server ?

All my pg options here: https://controlc.com/6489bca0

Comment: When I see that many `JOIN` operations in a select there's absolutely no mystery as to why it's slow. How's your index coverage on those tables? You need indexes on any of the associated matching columns or this could take forever and a half to run.

Comment: @tadman but the select is fast (3 sec)... so why would the insert be so slow ?

Comment: Probably a question for the [DBA crew](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Can you show EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the insert statement?